# Buttons not rendering in Gridview while binding Grid using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am binding the Gridview using WebMethod (JQuery), I have button inside Template field but it is not getting rendered at runtime. Button does get rendered when I bind the grid from aspx.cs code. I have tried with both HTML button and ASP.Net Button.
My code is as below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="EmpName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sDept" HeaderText="sDept" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

[image: Grid Image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a problem in jquery code. Here's an example that works

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetGrid",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});

function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var data = xml.find("Table"); 
    var row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true); 
    //$("[id*=GridView1] tr").not($("[id*=GridView1] tr:first-child")).remove();
    $.each(data, function () {
        $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("Id").text());
        $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("EmpName").text());
        $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("Salary").text());
        $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("sDept").text());
        $("[id*=GridView1]").append(row);
        row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
    });
}
```

where WebForm1.aspx/GetGrid is your form/method and Table is a name of your table